# Xamarin Forms access to all viewmodels

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use ViewModelLocator in my project.

I do BindingContent of ViewModelLocator in ResourceDictionary inside an app.xaml

My codes:

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controlsHelpers="clr-namespace:MyProj.Source.Helpers.UIHelper.ControlsHelpers;assembly=MyProj"
             xmlns:configuration="clr-namespace:MyProj.Source.Configuration;assembly=MyProj"
             x:Class="MyProj.App">
  <Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
      <configuration:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
      </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
 public class ViewModelLocator
 {
        public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
        public SignUpViewModel SignUpViewModel { get; set; }


        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            SignUpViewModel = new SignUpViewModel();
        }
 }
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel : AbstractViewModel
{

        private MyModel UserData { get; set; } = new MyModel();


        private bool _isSignRequired;


        public bool IsSignRequired
        {
            get { return _isSignRequired; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _isSignRequired) return;
                _isSignRequired = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return UserData.UserName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == UserData.UserName) return;
                UserData.UserName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return UserData.Password; }
            set
            {
                if (value == UserData.Password) return;
                UserData.Password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

}
```

**SignUpViewModel.cs**

```
public class SignUpViewModel : AbstractViewModel
{    
        private string _checkUserResultImage;

        public MyModel UserData { get; set; } = new MyModel();

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return UserData.Phone; }
            set
            {
                if (UserData.Phone != null && value == UserData.Phone) return;
                UserData.Phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return UserData.UserName; }
            set
            {
                if (UserData.UserName != null && value == UserData.UserName) return;
                UserData.UserName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return UserData.Password; }
            set
            {
                if (UserData.Password != null && value == UserData.Password) return;
                UserData.Password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get { return UserData.Email; }

            set
            {
                if (UserData.Email != null && value == UserData.Email) return;
                UserData.Email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string CheckUserResultImage
        {
            get { return _checkUserResultImage; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _checkUserResultImage) return;
                _checkUserResultImage = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public Command SignUpCommand
        {
           get
           {
               return new Command(async () =>
               {
                   //Here I want to get data field from LoginViewModel


               });
           }
        }
}
```

I want to get data from LoginViewModel in SignUpViewModel.

How can I do it?

Comment: add code for SignUpViewModel

Comment: add LoginViewModel too.

Comment: @santoshkumar done

Comment: Please check the answer perform the same in xamarin you will get it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is little bit more subtle and complex than I think you might realize.

You're asking "How do I get information from my LoginViewModel to my SignupViewModel?" There are lots of different ways to do this! Many of them, unfortunately, are bad, and go against the purpose of the MVVM design pattern. MVVM encourages decoupling of components, and encapsulation.

The most obvious, (and worst) way to do what you want is to simply get a reference to LoginViewModel inside SignupViewModel, and refer directly to its properties. Unfortunately, this is a very brittle solution, and enforces a hard dependency on your LoginViewModel. If your login flow ever changes, your SignupViewModel must change with it. Not ideal.

So, to avoid tight coupling of your components, you want to do something simpler: pass *only the data you're interested in*. There are lots of ways to do this too, such as events, parameter passing or a messaging system.

Events work okay, but I'd recommend against them, as it again forces your SignupViewModel to depend directly on your LoginViewModel. If you're okay with that though, it can work.

Parameter passing is probably the most lightweight solution, but unfortunately, Xamarin Forms doesn't support this out of the box. I've implemented it before, but it involves some work.

A messaging system that allows you to subscribe to, and publish, arbitrary messages is a very common solution (and indeed, events are actually a specific form of this). If you're looking for a quick drop-in solution, I think this might be your best bet, because the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) comes with a Messenger that does exactly this. Even if you don't use that exact implementation though, fundamentally, you would want to do something like this:

Lets say your Messenger implements some kind of interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IMessenger
{
    Publish<TMessage>(TMessage);
    Subscribe<TMessage>(object, Action<TMessage>); //the object here should be a reference to the recipient.
}
```

And then your implementation might look something like this:

You'd use this class for passing information:

```
public class LoginMessageArgs
{
    public string Username {get; private set;}
    //whatever other information this message needs to contain...         
}
```

Your LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : AbstractViewModel
{
    //all your properties go here...

    IMessenger messengerReference;

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        //Get a reference to your Messenger somehow. Maybe it's a singleton in ViewModelLocator?
        messengerReference = ViewModelLocator.Messenger;
    }

     //Maybe you call this method when you navigate away from the LoginViewModel, or whenever it makes sense to send this information to your SignupViewModel.
    private void PassLoginInformation()
    {
        messengerReference.Publish<LoginMessageArgs>(new LoginMessageArgs { Username = this.Username }); //etc
    }
}
```

Your SignupViewModel:

```
public class SignUpViewModel : AbstractViewModel
{

    //all your properties go here...

    public SignupViewModel()
    {
        //Get a reference to your Messenger somehow. Maybe it's a singleton in ViewModelLocator?
        IMessenger messengerReference = ViewModelLocator.Messenger;
        messenger.Register<LoginMessageArgs>(this, OnLoginMessageReceived);
    }

    private OnLoginMessageReceived(LoginMessageArgs message)
    {
        //Do stuff with your message
    }
}
```

Whew! Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to resolve my question. But i'm not sure that it good way.

I added BindingContext to the app.xaml

```
 <Application.BindingContext>
    <x:StaticResource Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
  </Application.BindingContext>
```

And I could get access to ViewModelLocator and to LoginViewModel.

```
var model=Application.Current.BindingContext as ViewModelLocator;
var login=model?.LoginViewModel.UserName;
```

Is it good practice?

Comment: to answer your question - read the answer above from PingZing